# Can a div be made to overflow uncontainably, like a select?

Tags: html, css

A select field when dropped down will overflow any of its containers, indeed even the browser window, but apart from that, can a div be made to behave in the same way, i.e. so that no properties of its containers will stop it overflowing them?

Comment: No, that can't be done. div is a DOM element, and the select box's extended area is a UI element of the browser

Comment: It wouldn't really fit the box-model of HTML, would it?

Comment: Thanks Ejay, good explanation. Would you like to repost this as an answer, so to receive your just deserts?